# How does one expand/unfold a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
                                 Counts
Unique_ID       Subcategory 
a1              A                10440
                B                  312
                C                  119
a2              A                  899
                B                   27
                C                   26
...
```

Each `Unique_ID` has three subcategories `A`, `B`, `C`, each with a count. There's a way to "unfold" this dataframe such that the Subcategories are columns, and the counts are entires. Here is what I would like:

```
Unique_ID       Subcategory_A      Subcategory_B      Subcategory_C
a1              10440              312                119
a2              899                27                 26
```

How does one do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) first, then remove top level of `MultiIndex` by [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html) and last [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df1 = df.unstack()
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(0)
df1 = df1.add_prefix('Subcategory_')
print (df1)
Subcategory  Subcategory_A  Subcategory_B  Subcategory_C
Unique_ID                                               
a1                   10440            312            119
a2                     899             27             26
```

If need reset index and remove columns name:

```
df1 = df.unstack()
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(0)
df1 = df1.add_prefix('Subcategory_')
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df1)
  Unique_ID  Subcategory_A  Subcategory_B  Subcategory_C
0        a1          10440            312            119
1        a2            899             27             26
```